# Warning message on running mongo.cursor.to.data.frame function in rmongodb

Tags: r, rmongodb

When I run the the query

```
mongo.cursor.to.data.frame(cursor)
```

to fetch the documents in a collection to a data frame in R using `rmongodb`, I am getting thewarning message:

```
In mongo.cursor.to.data.frame(cursor) : This fails for most NoSQL data structures. I am working on a new solution
```

I checked some articles about `rmongodb` and I could find this message mentioned there too. Does this warning mean that there might be some issues in the resulting data frame?

Answer (score 0):

The [source code](https://github.com/cran/rmongodb/blob/a94e98a92391fe8fff2cb129c4f413e5a21e58e2/R/mongo_cursor.R) shows where the issues **could** arise

```
mongo.cursor.to.data.frame <- function(cursor, nullToNA=TRUE, ...){

  warning("This fails for most NoSQL data structures. I am working on a new solution")

  res <- data.frame()
  while ( mongo.cursor.next(cursor) ){
    val <- mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(cursor))

    if( nullToNA == TRUE )
      val[sapply(val, is.null)] <- NA

    # remove mongo.oid -> data.frame can not deal with that!
    val <- val[sapply(val, class) != 'mongo.oid']

    res <- rbind.fill(res, as.data.frame(val, ... ))

  }
  return( as.data.frame(res) )
}
```

We can see it's using `plyr::rbind.fill` to `rbind` data.frames. So this all comes down to what is passed into `rbind.fill`, namely `val`.

And `val` is the result of `val <- mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(cursor))`.

So as long as `as.data.frame(val, ...)` can handle the list structure you pass into it you're ok.

However, it's quite easy to conceive a **NoSQL** data structure that will fail this:

```
## consider the JSON structure
## [{"a":[1,2,3],"b":["a","b","c"]},{"d":[1.1,2.2,3.3],"e":[["nested","list"]]}] 

##Which in R is the same as
lst = list(list(a = c(1L,2L,3L),
                b = c("a","b","c")),
           list(d = c(1.1, 2.2, 3.3),
                e = list(c("nested", "list"))))

## this errors when coerced to a data.frame
as.data.frame(lst)
Error in data.frame(d = c(1.1, 2.2, 3.3), e = list(c("nested", "list")),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 2
```

---

It's at this point I should mention the [`mongolite`](https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite) package, which is generally faster, but again returns a `data.frame`.

And there's also my extension to mongolite, [`mongolitedt`](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mongolitedt) (not yet on CRAN) that is quicker still and retrieving data, but again is limited by the result has to be coerced into a `data.table`